# WPF SurfaceButton that drops down SurfaceScrollViewer on click

Tags: c#, wpf, button, scrollviewer, surface

As the title says, I'd like to have a component whose base is SurfaceButton, and when clicked will drop down a SurfaceScrollViewer. I think I've made the proper first steps, but the SurfaceScrollViewer never becomes visible, nor does it seem to show in Blend's hierarchy. Am I accessing or initializing something incorrectly? I have multiple instances of SurfaceDropDown objects as children of a StackPanel, which is the content of another SurfaceScrollViewer. This parenting scroll viewer is aligned in a grid, which is why I set the heights and widths using the ActualHeight/Width properties.

```
public class SurfaceDropDown : SurfaceButton
{
    public SurfaceScrollViewer scrollViewer;
    private StackPanel stackPanel;

    public SurfaceDropDown()
    {
        this.Click += OnClick;

        scrollViewer = new SurfaceScrollViewer();

        scrollViewer.Height = this.ActualHeight * 5.0;
        scrollViewer.Width = this.ActualWidth;

        scrollViewer.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        scrollViewer.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
        scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

        stackPanel = new StackPanel();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            Label label = new Label();

            label.Content = "Label " + i.ToString();

            stackPanel.Children.Add(label);
        }

        scrollViewer.Content = stackPanel;

        scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += OnScroll;

        this.AddChild(scrollViewer);
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        scrollViewer.Visibility = scrollViewer.Visibility != Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void OnScroll(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Any help and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated!